# What's the math formula that is used to calculate maximum mortgage amount like in this calculator?

Tags: finance

What's the math formula that is used to calculate maximum mortgage amount like in this [calculator](https://www.google.com/search?q=mortgage%20loan%20calculator&source=hp&ei=Bmu4Y4vOAdLXkPIP-4y54AQ&iflsig=AJiK0e8AAAAAY7h5Fqknre7UehaRIEmqOgbkQ7QTqaai&oq=current%20interest%20rate%20for%2030%20&gs_lcp=Cgdnd3Mtd2l6EAMYATIFCAAQgAQyBQgAEIAEMgUIABCABDIFCAAQgAQyBQgAEIAEMgUIABCABDIFCAAQgAQyBQgAEIAEMgUIABCGAzIFCAAQhgM6EQguEIAEELEDEIMBEMcBENEDOggIABCABBCxAzoRCC4QgwEQxwEQsQMQ0QMQgAQ6DgguEIAEELEDEMcBENEDOgsIABCABBCxAxCDAToICC4QgwEQsQM6CAgAELEDEIMBOggILhCxAxCDAToLCC4QgAQQsQMQgwE6DggAEIAEELEDEIMBEMkDOg4ILhCABBCxAxCDARDUAjoLCC4QgAQQsQMQ1AI6EAgAEIAEELEDEIMBEEYQggI6CAgAEIAEEMkDOgYIABAWEB5QAFj5UWCWhwFoA3AAeAOAAdYCiAH0NZIBCDAuMjEuOS40mAEAoAEB&sclient=gws-wiz&si=AC1wQDC32zOmvFAE4VnOQP6g2h4cHtMkjcnsEGl6dXckSDJuy11bprGqXakHHKKz_R0A6uJY4yWmIUq9L9471lRyMrrXsr9ABOyRf9Vh-woP4G0dkiFuxRU%3D&ictx=1&ved=2ahUKEwjamJ_lzLP8AhVKfzABHaWIAh4QqPgFKAB6BAggEAM#tctx=monthly)?

**Visual Reference**: Take a look at these images to see which tool I'm specifically referring to:

[Purchase Budget with $0\%$ Interest](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RTcXz.png)

[Purchase Budget with $1\%$ Interest](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9ZeM3.png)

**Situation**: Right now I can calculate everything correctly while the interest rate is set at $0\%$. I'm having difficulty deriving the formula that takes into account the interest rate and how it impacts the Mortgage Amount/Purchase Budget.

The calculator I linked to has the Debt-to-Income Ratio set to $0.36$, so in my example images, a $\$10,000$ yearly income equates to $\$300,000$ in $30$ years, and $36\%$ of that $\$108,000$, which you can see in the first image with $0\%$ interest set.

All the other fields have a linear correlation to how much they affect the Mortgage Amount/Purchase Budget. For example, a $\$1$ monthly debt would result in a $\$360$ reduction of the budget ($\$1 \times 12$ months $\times 30$-year term).

**Attempts**:I tried seeing if the correlation was with the Mortgage Amortization, but it doesn't appear so from what I've tried.

**Context & Motivation**: I'm building my own personal finance/budgeting tool so that I can have every financial calculation in one place rather than utilizing various tools spread across various sites. An additional motivation is that the knowledge and understanding I gain from working on this can help someone else too.

**Update**: I solved this shortly after posting the question and posted my answer below. I see that someone else also provided a solution that can work too, but the one I posted fit better with my personal project.

Answer (score 2):

Your maximum monthly payment is 3% of your annual income.

The net present value of 360 monthly payments discounted at the rate of the loan gives your maximum mortgage balance.

$\text{Ballance} = \text{Payments}\sum_{n=1}^{360} \frac {1}{(1+\frac {y}{12})^n}$

Evaluating the sum of a geometric series.

$B = P\left(\frac {(1+\frac y{12})^{-1}(1- (1+\frac y{12})^{-360})}{1-(1+\frac {y}{12})^{-1}}\right)$

Which simplifies:

$B = P\left(\frac {1- (1+\frac y{12})^{-360}}{\frac {y}{12}}\right)$

Based on a $1\%$ loan and $\$300$ payment, the ballance would be $\$93,272.12$ which is within rounding of the $\$93,300$ in the link.

Answer (score -1):

I was able to solve this using [this resource](https://homeguides.sfgate.com/calculate-mortgage-amount-based-monthly-payments-3139.html).

That resource referenced the [Foner Books Formulas](https://www.fonerbooks.com/interest.htm).

**Below is what I used to solve:**

$G$ : Gross Annual Income

$g = \frac{G}{12}$ : Gross Monthly Income

$DTI$ : Debt-to-Income Ratio (Typically 36% of $g$)

$d$ : Monthly Debts (Car loan, School loan, Gas, Utilities, etc)

$f$ : Monthly Fees (Property Tax, Home Insurance, PMI, HOA)

$I$ : Interest Rate of Loan

$L$ : Loan Term (Eg. 30 Years)

$i = \frac{I}{12}$ : Monthly Interest Rate

$n = 12 \times L$ : Total Number of Payment Months

$y = (i+1)^n$

**Answer:**

***Affordable Mortgage Principal ($P$) Based on Interest Rate and DTI***

$P = \dfrac{DTI - d - f}{\dfrac{(i \times y)}{(y-1)}}$

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).